# Trouble getting smtp working on centos

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp

I've recently setup postfix on my server, I'm receiving mail from localhost but not from the outside nor can I send, doing a port scan says that there is nothing listening on port 25 and I've checked and its not a firewall issue.

I think its a problem with my config in main.cf. I've followed the walkthrough at [enter link description here](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix) but still think I've got something wrong. Here are the settings I've changed:

```
myhostname = local-server.local
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 10.0.1.0/8, 127.0.0.0/8
```

What have I done wrong?

Edit: netstat -tlnp brings up: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15970/master

Comment: What does "netstat -tlnp" say? Is there any listings for port 25?

Comment: No listing, guessing its not starting because of miss configuration.

Comment: Sorry stuffed up, localhost is listening on port 25. Gives me an idea so I'll have a look.

Comment: Nah haven't been able to get it to work yet, think of anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K, this was rather stupid, added this line

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

But forgot to remove / comment out this line:

```
#inet_interfaces = localhost
```

Commenting out fixed it.